# Oracle/Hibernate Like: Finding String that only contain a single ';'

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I'm trying to find all the records that contains only a single `;`  in a column.

For example

1. a;sdasd
2. as;dasd;dasd
3. as;dasd;das

only `a;sdasd` will be returned.

I have tried `%;%` but it will return all the strings that contain `;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id
  FROM your_table
 WHERE LENGTH(col) - LENGTH(REPLACE(col,';')) = 1;
```

Is one solution.

Another uses REGEXP_LIKE:

```
WITH q AS (SELECT 1 ID, 'a;b;c;' str FROM dual
           UNION
           SELECT 2, ';abc' FROM dual
           UNION 
           SELECT 3, 'a;b;c;defg;h' FROM dual
           UNION
           SELECT 4, 'abcdefghi;' FROM dual
           UNION 
           SELECT 5, 'ab;cde' FROM dual
           UNION 
           SELECT 6, 'abcdef' FROM dual)
SELECT *
  FROM q 
 WHERE regexp_like(str,'^[^;]*;[^;]*$');

        ID STR
---------- ------------
         2 ;abc
         4 abcdefghi;
         5 ab;cde
```

Comment: It probably forces a full table scan. But even a single like often results in a full table scan, i. e. an index on col wouldn't be used.

Comment: With this particular problem, you need to look at every value of the column of interest - the semicolon(s) could be anywhere. Depending on what you're selecting, it will at least require a full index scan (if the column of interest is indexed) regardless of how you do it.

Comment: if I am looking for column that has only a single ";" in between texts?

Answer (score 0):

Ine other possibility (no String manipulation is necessary):

```
FROM your_table
   WHERE col like '%;%' AND INSTR(col, ';', 1) = INSTR(col, ';', -1)
```